# Open Source Excel Engine for Sharepoint 2007

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I was wondering if you knew of any Open Source or paid Excel engine which we could use without going down the Sharepoint 2007 MOSS route?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try [SmartXLS for .Net](http://www.smartxls.com),it support most Excel features(formats,charts,pivot tables,formula evaluations etc).